# Rails form for model function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to run this function on my View somehow, and i cannot figure out how to make it, everywhere are forms with controllers. How to make it work?

models/feed.rb

```
class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.update_from_feed(feed_url, category)
    add_feed(feed_url, category)
  end
end
```

views/feeds/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for Feed.update_from_feed(feed_url, category) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :feed_url %>
  <%= f.text_field :category %>
  <%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: your question doesn't make sense at all. Please elaborate what your are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have a method on my Model, which im calling now from console. And i want to call it from website view. I need to write feed_url and category, and run this function from my Model.

Comment: but you are trying to call the model method in form "action". that part makes no sense at all. also if you need to call a model method on some event like button click or form submit, then you send a request to the controller and in the controller you call the model method.

Comment: Seems ok for me. But how then looks my controller? Its hard for me with forms and i must do it today..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a route in config/routes.rb file. This is where your request will go upon some event like button click or form submit. Then when you submit the form(form action will be this route's url) or when you click a button a request should go to the controller method. In the controller you can call the model methods.

For example,
I have a products controller. In the Products controller there is an action called 'search'. I will set up a route in config/routes.rb file to map to this controller action 'search'. So Rails will route all requests on this url to my Products controller's search method.

You need to setup a similar action in one of your controllers(based on design) and send request to the route that maps to this controller action

Please refer http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ for better understanding.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html